# Обводка в виде тени вокруг View

Tags: android

Можно ли программно или через разметку сделать тень вокруг `View`, чтобы она была равномерная по периметру и заданной ширины, как на приведенном рисунке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели нет идей, как сделать такую тень для разных кнопок и других ui? Ну не рисовать же png тень картинки для каждой кнопки и других View под все размеры..

Answer (score 0):

А использовать View.setElevation() и View.setTranslationZ() как в документации по Material Design https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping?hl=ru не пробовали?

Comment: Там же вроде тень со смещением вниз.. Мне надо чтобы равномерная по периметру была, как на рисунке, что я выше привел..